# Strange folder showing up when using git flow on Windows

Tags: windows, git, windows-10, git-flow

I am new to git-flow. I am playing around with it to get a feel for it. I am running git 2.6.2 on Windows 10. Most things seem to work fine, but I have run into this problem:

I create two feature branches with conflicting content. Then I finish them both. When I finish the second, I naturally get a conflict, which I can then resolve. However, at that point git flow seems to have created a strange folder.

```
> git flow feature start PPLAN-0007_Doubles
    [make change to files]
> git commit -am "PPLAN-0007: overloaded add
    [make more change to files]
> git commit -am "PPLAN-0007: overloaded subtract"
> git flow feature start PPLAN-0008_single
    [make conflicting change to files]
> git commit -am "PPLAN-0008: overloaded add"
    [make more change to files]
> git commit -am "PPLAN-0008: overloaded subtract"
> git flow feature finish PPLAN-0007_Doubles
> git flow feature finish PPLAN-0008_single --showcommands
Branches 'develop' and 'origin/develop' have diverged.
And local branch 'develop' is ahead of 'origin/develop'.
git checkout develop
Already on 'develop'
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/develop' by 3 commits.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)
git merge --ff feature/PPLAN-0008_single
Auto-merging Math.cs
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in Math.cs
Recorded preimage for 'Math.cs'
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.

There were merge conflicts. To resolve the merge conflict manually, use:
    git mergetool
    git commit

You can then complete the finish by running it again:
    git flow feature finish PPLAN-0008_single
> git mergetool
    [fix merge conflict]
> git status
On branch develop
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/develop' by 3 commits.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)
All conflicts fixed but you are still merging.
  (use "git commit" to conclude merge)

Changes to be committed:

        modified:   Math.cs

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

        "(cd .git \357\200\276/"
```

As you can see, I now have a strange untracked file. It is actually a folder structure that has been created. It looks like this in `GitExtensions`:

[image]

It looks like something a unix command would create.

None of the `git flow` commands report any errors. The file actually seems to have been created immediately after the second finish command. It doesn't really matter if I resolve the conflicts or not.

What is going on? Am I doing something wrong? Something that needs to be configured?

I do have what seems to be a workaround: I can delete the strange file, and then continue with `git flow feature finish PPLAN-0008_single`.

Comment: Which version of git-flow are you using?

Comment: @PetervanderDoes the one packaged with git 2.6.2, installed using Chocolatey, with the command `choco install git`

Comment: No idea what version that is. What does "git flow version" tell you?

Comment: @PetervanderDoes `1.9.0-dev.59 (AVH Edition)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bug in git-flow AVH Edition, which is fixed in version 1.9.1 of the software.

Chocolatey needs to be updated with this version. If possible, you need to file a bug report with Chocolatey.